# Book where a brother and sister fall into a book of fairy tales

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai

I read this around 5-6 years ago, so the details I remember are really vague.

What I remember:

- There was a brother and a sister (I think the brother was Connor and the sister, Alex).
- The sister finds out about a magical book and starts dropping pencils into it and the pencils vanish.
- The sister hops into the book and the brother follows her.
- The two fall into a sort of fantasy kingdom where they meet a frog.
- To get back to their world, they start to gather magical objects to form a spell that gives them a wish.
- > They gather the objects but then some sort of storytale villain stops them and makes their own wish.
- They meet their grandmother and go back to the modern world.

Is there a book that fits this description?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty sure this is one of the *The Land of Stories* books by Chris Colfer.

Probably the first book, *[The Wishing Spell](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11607446-the-wishing-spell)*.

The kids names and story fit.

Goodreads says this about the first book.

> Alex and Conner Bailey's world is about to change, in this fast-paced adventure that uniquely combines our modern day world with the enchanting realm of classic fairy tales.
> The Land of Stories tells the tale of twins Alex and Conner. Through the mysterious powers of a cherished book of stories, they leave their world behind and find themselves in a foreign land full of wonder and magic where they come face-to-face with the fairy tale characters they grew up reading about.
>
> But after a series of encounters with witches, wolves, goblins, and trolls alike, getting back home is going to be harder than they thought